# Interpreting $a^2b \div \frac13a^2b^3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The maths book I'm using shows:
$$ a^2b \div \frac13a^2b^3 $$
Which would be something like:
$$ a^2 \cdot b ÷ \frac13 \cdot a^2 \cdot b^3 $$
My understanding of order of operations it would equal:
$$ 3a^4b^4 $$
However in the book the second term is evaluated before the division (switching it to multiplication) and equaling:
$$ a^2b \cdot \frac{3}{a^2b^3} = \frac{3a^2b}{a^2b^3} = \frac{3}{b^2} $$
If a multiplication or division signs shows between terms, should that be taken as multiplying or dividing one term by the other?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but $\div$ should never be used for anything because of exactly these issues. If you do this in a book, you are basically asking for confusion.

Comment: Your initial interpretation is, to me, the technically correct one. That said, it's *not-entirely-unreasonable* that the author intended the expression to be read as $\left(a^2b\right)\div\left(\frac13a^2b^3\right)$, believing that the "$\div$" provided a clear-enough separation between components of the division operation. Even so, parentheses were invented to prevent this kind of confusion, and the author should know better.

Comment: @Blue No, I would say $(a^2b\div\frac13)a^2b^3$ would not be the correct interpretation, because the multiplication signs are omitted for a reason.  Same as "... divided by two pi" is universally interpreted as $\dots/(2\pi)$ rather than $(\dots/2)\times\pi$.  But I know this has been a subject of flame wars for at least a quarter century now.

Comment: @user10354138: I agree that "... divided by two pi" is clear. Perhaps *you'll* agree that, say, "ecks divided by wye pi" is less-so; does it mean "$x/(y\pi)$" or "$(x/y)\pi$"? (Pauses, and lack thereof, can help: "ecks ... divided by wyepi" vs "ecksdividedbywye ... pi".) Anyway ... A student who may be unaware that symbolic math allows nuance, and who has had the non-nuanced order-of-operations relentlessly hammered into his head, might not realize that the visual separation afforded by "$\div$" can *count* as a grouping strategy. In a textbook, it's probably best not to assume that he will.

Comment: Nice video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4x-BcYCiKCk and also this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLCDca6dYpA

Answer (score 2):

All books I have seen state:

- $x:yz = \cfrac{x}{y}z$
- $x:(yz) = \cfrac{x}{yz}$

And I know only these as a rule.

Comment: Approximately how many books have you seen for that result? Can you name the best one of them?

Comment: @TShiong Two or three books. I didn't learn the basics of mathematics in English, so I cannot name them, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

In this form

$$a^2b \div \frac13a^2b^3$$

my interpretation is to consider the two terms as a whole, that is
$$\left(a^2b\right) \div \left(\frac13a^2b^3\right)=\frac{3a^2b}{a^2b^3}=\frac 3 {b^2}$$

Otherwise, in this form

$$a^2 \times b ÷ \frac13 \times a^2 \times b^3$$

whithout parenthesis my interpretation would be

$$a^2 \times \left(b ÷ \frac13\right) \times a^2 \times b^3=3a^4b^4$$

Comment: I would call the second form “dodgy, don’t do it”.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes I agree, parentheses should be used but following the ordinary rules I would proceed as indicated.

Comment: should your answer be $\frac{3}{b^2}$ for the top answer.

Comment: @EM4 Yes of course, I fix the typo.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual interpretation is that writing two things side by side without a visible operator means they are multiplied with higher priority than normal multiplication or division using a visible operator. So we multiply 1/3, $a^2$ and $b^3$ first.